# WDK (Windows Driver Kit) issues with utility library (std::unique_ptr)

Tags: c++, windows, driver, wdk

I am currently playing around with the WDK and wanted to use std::unique_ptr with a custom deleter to avoid calling `ObDereferenceObject, ExFreePoolWithTag`. But it seems that when including `<utility>` the project just breaks and isn't working, i.e showing that no overload matches (no `T*`) the input for my unique ptr.
When using the same code in a "regular" project everything works fine.

```
#include <memory>
struct PoolDeleter
{
    void operator( )(void* arg) const
    {
        if (arg)
            ExFreePoolWithTag(arg, 0);
    }
};

using PoolBuffer = std::unique_ptr<void, PoolDeleter>;

// Example inside functions

PoolBuffer buffer{ ExAllocatePoolZero(NonPagedPool, 0x2000, POOL_TAG) };
```

This produces

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "std::unique_ptr<_Ty, _Dx>::unique_ptr [with _Ty=void, _Dx=PoolDeleter]" matches the argument list
```

indicating that there is no overload with `T*`. Also when adding `<memory>` the whole solution errors with multiple errors.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "_Mbstatet" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio   38  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "snprintf"  Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio   84  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vfscanf"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio   86  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vscanf"    Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio   87  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vsscanf"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdio   88  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "lldiv_t"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  66  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "atoll" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  73  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "llabs" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  74  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "lldiv" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  75  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "strtof"    Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  76  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "strtold"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  77  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "strtoll"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  78  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "strtoull"  Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  79  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "_Exit" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  81  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "at_quick_exit" Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  82  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "quick_exit"    Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cstdlib  83  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vfwscanf"  Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   88  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vswscanf"  Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   89  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "vwscanf"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   90  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "wcstof"    Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   91  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "wcstold"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   92  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "wcstoll"   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   93  
Error (active)  E0282   the global scope has no "wcstoull"  Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\cwchar   94  
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\limits   1094    
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory   3578    
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory   3583    
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory   3589    
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory   3610    
Error (active)  E0864   enable_if_t is not a template   Driver.sys (Driver\Driver.sys) - x64-Debug  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\memory   3717    
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\vcruntime.h(61): error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\vcruntime.h(61): warning C4083: expected ')'; found identifier '_VCRUNTIME_DISABLED_WARNINGS'
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\vcruntime.h(111): warning C4005: '_CRT_STRINGIZE': macro redefinition
  F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\crtdefs.h(85): note: see previous definition of '_CRT_STRINGIZE'
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\vcruntime.h(114): warning C4005: '_CRT_WIDE': macro redefinition
  F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\crtdefs.h(88): note: see previous definition of '_CRT_WIDE'
F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\vcruntime.h(155): warning C4005: '__CRTDECL': macro redefinition
  F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\crtdefs.h(640): note: see previous definition of '__CRTDECL'
F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\yvals.h(35): warning C4005: '_STD': macro redefinition
  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\yvals_core.h(1281): note: see previous definition of '_STD'
F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\yvals.h(37): warning C4005: '_STD_END': macro redefinition
  F:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include\yvals_core.h(1280): note: see previous definition of '_STD_END'
F:\Program Files\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.22000.0\km\crt\xstddef(26): fatal error C1189: #error:  "_HAS_EXCEPTIONS == 0 is not supported."
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I am using the latest `Windows 11 EWDK`.

Is there any fix for that or is it just impossible to use `std::unique_ptr` in driver ? Otherwise I would just create a simple wrapper class that handles the cleanup for me but using smart pointers would be nicer since this is pretty much reinventing the wheel.

Regards Artur

Comment: Why do you include `<utility>` whereas `std::unique_ptr` is in `<memory>`? You would better post the complete errors message instead of your description.

Comment: @S.M. I edited the initial question with the exact code and errors. I somehow got confused there my bad. `<utility>` is for `std::pair`

Comment: The errors are in Ouput tab. What you posted is Error List.

Comment: you can not use c/c++ runtime in kernel mode

Comment: @S.M. Added
@RbMm Are you aware of any other better way then creating a wrapper class and then calling `ExFreePoolWithTag` in the dtor to not manually handle the cleanup ?

Answer (score 2):

The C++ runtime for the NT kernel does not include support for C++ exceptions. Unfortunately, that breaks much of the C++ STL. The official C++ spec does not (yet) have any allowance for an exception-free subset of the STL, and the maintainers of the Microsoft STL have not (yet) officially committed to supporting such a subset.

Unofficially, the maintainers of the Microsoft STL do want a few foundational headers like `<type_traits>` to be usable in an NT kernel context. So you may find that a few headers do work in kernel mode on a best-effort basis. Since [the Microsoft STL is open-source](https://github.com/microsoft/stl), you can help with their unofficial project to make bits of their STL work in the NT kernel.

Alternatively, there are several C++ libraries out there that do commit to offering STL-like features without requiring C++ exception support. For example, [the wil library](https://github.com/microsoft/wil) includes a `wistd_memory.h` that offers roughly the same interface as `<memory>`, except under a `wistd::` namespace, including a `wistd::unique_ptr<T>`. The wil library is maintained by the Windows team at Microsoft, and is used extensively across the Windows codebase, including in several core kernel drivers.

You can probably find several other C++ libraries that offer a reasonable `std::unique_ptr` replacement if you search for C++ libraries that don't throw exceptions. You can quickly determine a library is not suitable for the NT kernel if grep shows it using the keywords `throw` or `catch`.

Aside from C++ exceptions, that there's one other gotcha with the C++ runtime in NT kernel: the runtime doesn't come with a global `operator new` and `operator delete`. You'll need to [provide your own `operator new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new), either globally and/or as a member on all your classes. Fortunately, this is a small amount of boilerplate you can just drop into any C++ driver project.

Comment: Thanks for this awesome response. I will check the wil library and see if this is enough, as I am just interested in cleaning up the pools automatically since its sometimes hard to keep track of it.